# Parse <a:FileContent> parameter in XML response

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a web service that returns a response and I cant seem to find a good answer on how to parse the a:FileContent parameter using php or c#

The response looks like:

```
<GetReturnFileResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<GetReturnFileResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SigmaAPIService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <a:FileContent>/*Byte[] data type long string looks like 'IkRWTEoxMDI2LkVGQiIsIkVGVCIsIjgxOCIsIlZBTlNQRVlCUk9FQ0siLCIxMC8yNi8xNSIsIjA3Mzk3MjE4MSIsIjcwMDA3ODc5MDY5MDUwJSMDEiLCIxMC8yOC8xNSIsIlBCIiLCIiDQo=' here. **removed some chars just a sample*/</a:FileContent>
    <a:Response>
        <a:ResponseCode>1</a:ResponseCode>
        <a:ResponseMessage>Successfully processed</a:ResponseMessage>
        <a:ResponseType>Success</a:ResponseType>
    </a:Response>
</GetReturnFileResult>
```

Comment: The "url here" values are the actual namespaces, they are important. You register aliases for the namespaces and use them in Xpath. Additionally it would be a good idea to limit the question to one environment and show what you have tried.

Comment: Thank you I added the urls, my attempts were limited to

`byte[] byteArray = "IkRWTEoxMDI2LkVGQiIsIkVGVCIsIjgxOCIsIlZBTlNQRVlCUk9FQ0siLCIxMC8yNi8=";
            
string bytetest = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);`

Comment: I couldnt really find a starting point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy with xml Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
                "<GetReturnFileResponse xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">" +
                  "<GetReturnFileResult xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SigmaAPIService\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" +
                    "<a:FileContent>/*Byte[] data type long string looks like 'IkRWTEoxMDI2LkVGQiIsIkVGVCIsIjgxOCIsIlZBTlNQRVlCUk9FQ0siLCIxMC8yNi8xNSIsIjA3Mzk3MjE4MSIsIjcwMDA3ODc5MDY5MDUwJSMDEiLCIxMC8yOC8xNSIsIlBCIiLCIiDQo=' here. **removed some chars just a sample*/</a:FileContent>" +
                    "<a:Response>" +
                      "<a:ResponseCode>1</a:ResponseCode>" +
                      "<a:ResponseMessage>Successfully processed</a:ResponseMessage>" +
                      "<a:ResponseType>Success</a:ResponseType>" +
                    "</a:Response>" +
                  "</GetReturnFileResult>" +
                "</GetReturnFileResponse>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            XElement fileContent = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "FileContent").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace ns_a = fileContent.Name.Namespace;
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Great so far but how do I output the contents of the file from that? I tried

`Console.WriteLine(fileContent);
            Console.ReadLine();`

Just to get a feeling of what I am working with but not really able to convert the byte[] into useful output

Comment: The data is either encrypted or packed like a zip file.  See following webpage : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30561/Using-ZIP-content-for-delivery-over-HTTP

Comment: Thanks that was what I needed a resource to understand what was going on.

Comment: You may want to use a sniffer like fiddler or wireshark to view the url data.  They will automatically unzip data to confirm is data is zip.

Comment: The text wizard in Fiddler worked like a dream all of this combined got me the answers I needed from the Response. Thanks!